# No Directionality Widget Found with ListView in Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to show a ListView of the data i gort in my Cloud Firestore Database named Exercises:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: db.collection('Exercises').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else
            return ListView(
              children: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.map((doc) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(doc.data()['name']),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when i do this i get the Error in my App:
[Image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgRzm.png)

Thank you for your help

Comment: you need `MaterialApp` as a root widget, so instead of `Scaffold > StreamBuilder > ...` you need `MaterialApp > Scaffold > StreamBuilder > ...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it works. Have a nice day

Comment: sure, your welcome, have a nice day too

Answer (score 0):

Can't Use StreamBuilder directly into the scaffold, Add Column or SinglechildScrollview or Container.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(  // Column, Singlechild Scroll view Here
        children: [
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: db.collection('Exercises').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else
                return ListView(
                  children: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.map((doc) {
                    return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(doc.data()['name']),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If You Found Null-Saftey error, Use Stream in init() function. Then Call the stream

Comment: First thank you for your answer. I tried it with the Column and with the SinglechildScrollview, but then i get another Error, that a MediaQuery Widget is missing in the Scaffold

Answer (score 0):

First thank you for your answer. I tried it with the Column and with the SinglechildScrollview, but then i get another Error, that a MediaQuery Widget is missing

[MediaQuery Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BpRS.png)